# Generic struct with no fields of type T, only methods

Tags: file, generics, rust, struct

Im trying to create a struct which can be used to read and write to file with generic parameters.

I have several methods on this struct which take a generic type T, but the struct itself does not have any fields of type T.

Here is the code:

```rust
pub struct AccessObject<T: Identifiable + Serialize + DeserializeOwned> {
    pub indexes: String,
    pub file_names: Vec<String>,
}

impl<T: Identifiable + Serialize + DeserializeOwned> AccessObject<T> {
    pub fn new(indexes: &String, file_names: Vec<String>) -> AccessObject<T> {
        return AccessObject {
            indexes: indexes.clone(),
            file_names,
        };
    }

    pub fn get(&self, id: u64) -> Option<T> {
        let index_dao = IndexDao::new(&self.indexes);

        return match index_dao.get(id) {
            Some(index) => {
                let mut file = file_op::connect(&self.file_names[index.file_number as usize]);

                file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(index.file_position));

                let read = file_op::read::<T>(&mut file).unwrap();
                Some(read)
            }
            None => None,
        };
    }
}
```

I would like to keep the references to `indexes` and `file_names`, hence the struct. I would like to be able to create other structs with the generic one, something like this:

```rust
pub struct GraphAccessObject {
    pub access_object: AccessObject<Graph>,
}
```

Initially I had implemented the AccessObject struct as a trait, but I realised I was repeating a lot of code writing the same thing for each struct I implemented the trait for.

The problem is I get an error on my generic struct saying that there are no fields with type T and so to remove the generic parameter. Is there a way I can do this other than just implementing the methods on their own outside of the struct?

Can I implement a trait for several types at once?

Comment: You probably want to take a look at [`std::marker::PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html).

Comment: huh @Finomnis that seems super clunky, but it does work. Is this commonly used? Seems like it might be a code smell

Comment: Why does the struct need the `T` parameter in the first place? Can't you just omit it and include it only as a constraint on the methods?

Comment: Ah I see. PhantomData is not a code smell in itself, but your approach is weird and probably smelly.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a smell. Rust can't have unused generics due to technical reasons, so `PhantomData` is there to 'dummy-use' the generic. Having unused generics is unusual, but if that's the API you would like to have, I think it's a legitimate usecase for `PhantomData`.

Comment: Also, please provide a [MRE], your code does not compile due to many missing `use` statements, so it's hard to write an actual answer. I always check that the answers I provide actually work, and I can't do that in this case.